# how to set Boolean value per row based on condition

Tags: sql, presto

I want to set column called `is_last_status` on my table based on the `role_end_date`

For example:

Example 1:

```
role_end_date role_start_date   row_id     id is_last_status

null           2020-02-08   7_2020-02-08    7   true

2020-02-07     2019-11-05   7_2019-11-05    7   false

2019-11-05     2019-07-16   7_2019-07-16    7   false

2019-07-16     2019-05-28   7_2019-05-28    7   false

2019-05-24     2019-04-24   7_2019-04-24    7   false
```

Example 2:

```
role_end_date role_start_date   row_id     id is_last_status

2020-04-01     2020-02-08   6_2020-02-08    6   true

2020-01-01     2020-01-01   6_2020-01-01    6   false
```

I can't seem to find the SQL that can generate the `is_last_status` I'm having difficulties with the gaps.

**Logic is:**
There can be only 1 row with `is_last_status = True`.
It should be the most recent row in the table based on `role_start_date`

So in both examples the most recent row is `role_start_date = '2020-02-08'`
Basically if the row has `role_start_date=Max(role_start_date)` set is_last_status to True, rest are false.
`role_start_date` is unique per `id`.

I should be something with:

```
SELECT
    role_end_date
    ,role_start_date
    ,row_id
    ,id
    ,LEAD(role_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY role_end_date) as is_last_status
FROM my_table
```

I'm using Presto

Comment: how are you calculating `is_last_status` ?

Comment: @zealous see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using `row_number()`

```
select
        role_end_date
        ,role_start_date
        ,row_id
        ,id
        ,case when rnk = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end as is_last_status
from
(
    select
        role_end_date
        ,role_start_date
        ,row_id
        ,id
        ,row_number() over (partition by id order by role_start_date desc) as rnk
    from my_table
) val
order by
    role_start_date desc
```

Comment: I thought of this. Will definitely work I was wondering if there is easier way to do this.

Comment: Do you think this can be combined to 1 query so it won't need two SELECTs?

Comment: @HaloKu I do not think so. sorry about it.